# Where is the documentation for wxAUIToolbar?

Tags: documentation, wxwidgets, wxauitoolbar

I looked in http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/ but could't find the documentation for it.

Does anyone know where it is and/or why it's not there?

Comment: A deleted answer gave [this link](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_aui.html), which I think is worth reproducing in the comments. The documentation in relation to this control is, it would seem, not much improved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can explain why it's not there in a sense - there's no Doxygen annotations in the header file where the class is declared. As for why not, I'm guessing that the AUI authors isn't a big fan of Doxygen - I believe AUI was developed as a third party addition to wxWidgets, and has only relatively recently been merged in, so a few differences in things like this are to be expected.

The class is declared in include/wx/aui/auibar.h, it inherits wxControl, and from a quick look through the public methods it's probably not that hard to figure out.

There are some wxAuiToolbar examples in the aui sample program (samples/aui/auidemo.cpp). This should give a few more clues.

Until someone contributes some documentation updates, I'm afraid a bit of detective work is probably needed.

Comment: Ya, thanks. That's kinda what I thought. Just for the record, the AUI components were developed by Kirix Corp. and 'donated' to wxWidgets for inclusion.